# Unable to import a module from another module in Nuxt

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

In my nuxt directory structure I have a folder called `modules` which contains my custom modules. In this example it will contain the modules `foo` and `bar`. In `nuxt.config.js` `foo` is added like so:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
...
modules: [
  ...
  "~/modules/foo"
],
...
```

Note `bar` is not added as a module.
When I try to import `bar` in `foo`

```js
// foo/index.ts

import { bar } from '~/modules/bar';

export default function fooModule() {
  console.log(bar)
}
```

```js
// bar/index.ts

const bar = 1
export { bar };

export default function barModule() {}
```

I get `Nuxt Fatal Error`, `Error: Cannot find module '~/modules/bar'`.
Adding `"~/modules/bar"` to `modules` in `nuxt.config.js` seems to make no difference.

Any Idea on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module is something designed with Nuxt in mind, something like the [axios module](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup) is to be added this way in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios']
}
```

You cannot dump your own code just like that into `modules`.

---

You're probably looking for [plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins) here?

Comment: Im not sure I thought plugins where meant to inject functionality into the Vue context (preferably I would like to import `foo` and `bar` using an import statement at the top of the script)? I might be misunderstanding the use of plugins, Ill look into this, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the difference between `plugins` and `modules` can be hard to understand at first. Meanwhile, you need to also know that writing it as a plugin will link it globally to the project. If it's not needed, feel free to simply import it per component/page for performance reasons. @DominiqueGarmier

Comment: If not in `/plugins` where would you put those `.ts` files? Is there a best practice? From what I understand I could put them in `/assets` but the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets) says it's meant for images, styles, fonts etc.

Comment: @DominiqueGarmier usually, a `/utils/` is an okay directory (at the root of the project), I'm doing it this way and all the people I worked with before with are doing the same.

Comment: So I moved all my "utils" to `/utils`. But the problem remains. I have one module in `/modules` (which needs to be there), it injects a plugin into the Vue-context. And imports from `/utils`, which apparently doesn't exit during the build process. Giving me again `Error: Cannot find module '~/utils/...'`

Comment: Try with `'@/utils/...'`, `@` being the root of the project.